# Windows CRT and assert reporting (abort, retry, ignore)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

The Windows CRT in debug mode will show a **Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library** dialog with **Abort, Retry, Ignore** options if the application hits an CRT error or `assert(false)` and sometimes it is created many times and fills the screen.
This dialog can contain lines like "Debug Assertion Failed" or "Debug Error!".

I would love it if the assert would break directly into the debugger skipping the dialog.

I have modified the [CRT reporting flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y71x448(VS.80).aspx) which have had no effect.
I have also tried to modify the [reporting hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94a21kwy(VS.80).aspx). It does get called by after 25-30 "Abort" dialogs appear.

I am building a DLL that is loaded by a separate program if that helps. It also looks like the  host program loading my DLL is not consistent with what thread is calling my code.
It seems like the one of the threads was stopped but the others are still running.

How do I configure the CRT to do this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works (for me atleast, on vs 2008):
(Essentially, return TRUE from the hooked function)

```
int __cdecl CrtDbgHook(int nReportType, char* szMsg, int* pnRet)
{
    return TRUE;//Return true - Abort,Retry,Ignore dialog will *not* be displayed
    return FALSE;//Return false - Abort,Retry,Ignore dialog *will be displayed*
}
int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])
{
    _CrtSetReportHook2(_CRT_RPTHOOK_INSTALL, CrtDbgHook);
    assert(false);
    getch();
    return 1;
}
```

You could also write your own assert-like behavior (Note that this will show the "Break, Continue" dialog):

```
#define MYASSERT(x) { if(!(x)) {DbgRaiseAssertionFailure();} }

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])
{
    MYASSERT(false);
    getch();
    return 1;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve my problem.
I get about 25-30 Abort,Retry,Ignore dialogs before the CrtDbgHook is called.

Answer (score 3):

Liao's answer takes you most of the way there, but I'd like to propose that you add one more thing to your debug hook:

```
int __cdecl StraightToDebugger(int, char*, int*)
{
  _CrtDbgBreak(); // breaks into debugger
  return TRUE; // handled -- don't process further.
}
```

Otherwise your assertions will just disappear and the process will terminate.

Problem with this approach is that -- at least for my home install of VC Express -- the debugger throws up a big "program.exe has triggered a breakpoint" message instead of the normal Assertion Failure, so it may not be a great improvement.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you want the behavior to be for any `assert`, or whether you're just trying to use `assert(false)` specifically as a general-purpose pattern to unconditionally break into debugger on a given line. If it's the former, see Liao's and Kim's answers. If it's the latter, then you should really use the [`__debugbreak`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f408b4et.aspx) intrinsic function instead.

Comment: Is the difference that `assert` will ask to break and trigger only in debug builds while `__debugbreak` will just break regardless?

Comment: __debugbreak literally puts a breakpoint instruction (e.g. INT 3 on x86) in your code - so it will break in any build, and it will not show the nice message box with the text etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why does it assert? assert(false) looks like "should never happen" code was executed in CRT. I would be scared if I were you. Is it always on one line? Are there any comments around it?

EDIT:
I mean: assert happens in CRT code because there is some assumption it is checking that you don't meet (maybe you managed to link to mixed runtime, or you making managed C++ assembly and forgot to manually initialize CRT, or you trying to call LoadLibrary from within DllMain, or some other thing that should never happen).

So before figuring out how to suppress asserts, find out why exactly does it assert in the first place. Otherwise you'll likely get seemengly unrelated problems later on and will have lots of fun trying to debug them. (from your question it is unclear if you know what those asserts are about)

Code like this

```
if(somebadcondition)
{
    assert(false);
    // recovery code
}
```

literally means "this branch of code should never be executed".

Comment: do you mean why assert(false) asserts ? its because when you assert, the condition should evaluate to true to be "ok", the thinking being "assert that a+b=4", so if a+b is not equal to 4, the "assertion has failed".

Comment: sorry, i dint understand your last 2 questions - is what always on one line ? any comments "around" it - what do you mean?

Comment: You are absolutely right in that one should first figure out why an assert is occurring. And using assert(false); is certainly one way to ensure that "this branch of code should never be executed". +1 for adding more info/correct practice to this, that i neglected to do.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [DebugBreak Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679297(VS.85).aspx)?

Or even use an opcode?

```
#ifdef _X86_
#define BreakPoint()        _asm { int 3h }
#else
#define BreakPoint()        DebugBreak()
#endif
```

> [Before Visual C++ 2005, the instruction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/45yd4tzz.aspx),
>
> `__asm int 3` did not cause native code to be generated when compiled with
>   /clr; the compiler translated the
>   instruction to a CLR break
>   instruction. Beginning in Visual C++
>   2005, __asm int 3 now results in
>   native code generation for the
>   function. If you want a function to
>   cause a break point in your code and
>   if you want that function compiled to
>   MSIL, use __debugbreak.

Comment: I don't want to change the definition of the assert macro.
This is not just for my code but also for static libraries that I link against which also use the assert macro