# Setting a breakpoint on calling abort()

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2012, breakpoints, abort

I am debugging an application and for some reason (which I'm not quite sure), when closing my application `abort()` is called. I'd like to try and find the reason for this, so I want to place a breakpoint on `abort()` so I can see the stack trace and hopefully discover the reason it was called instead of a graceful exit.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 (Update 3) and only have the declaration for the `abort()` function (in `stdlib.h`) and so I can't set a breakpoint. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Ctrl+D, N.  Type "abort" for the function name.

Comment: @HansPassant I had to use Ctrl-B, but that worked, thank you very very much! The problem was I wasn't handling one of my threads correctly and so the destructor called `abort()`!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special. `abort` call from C/C++ program built by Visual Studio produces the following message:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual C++ Debug Library
---------------------------
Debug Error!
Program: ...
R6010
- abort() has been called
(Press Retry to debug the application)
---------------------------
Abort   Retry   Ignore   
---------------------------
```

Pressing Retry opens debugger with full call stack. This functionality is available both for Debug and Release configurations, when program runs in standalone mode and under debugger. In Release configuration the dialog is different, it contains Break button, which opens debugger, like Retry in Debug configuration.

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for your response, I do get a similar message in the `Output` debug box in Visual Studio however I do not get a dialog with a `Retry` button which I can press (I assume because I'm already closing the application at this point)?

Comment: According to MSDN: `When the application is linked with a debug version of the run-time libraries, abort creates a message box with three buttons: Abort, Retry, and Ignore`.

Comment: In my test it works, to build with Debug CRT version, there is the following option: C/C++ - Code Generation - Runtime Library - Multi-threaded Debug DLL.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if it's a peculiarity with my particular code then, because I am running it with the Multi-threaded debug CRT and I don't receive such a message box, I just get presented with a trace message in the `Output` box (and then all threads exiting with return value `3`). I created a new project with exactly the same settings put with just an `abort()` and `return 0;`  statement in the `main()` function and it behaves as expected, but for some reason not in my project.

Comment: And if you want to suppress this message into actual breakpoint or custom behaviour: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1151175/10141885

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found this answer which works for me:  Press CTRL+B and enter 'abort' in the text field.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me with a service. My hotkey was different than CTRL+B. But I just added it through the Breakpoints window.

Answer (score 0):

Just for debug, you may overrides `abort` function and set a breakpoint inside.

```
void abort()
{
    std::cout << "aborting" << std::endl; // put break here...
    exit(-1);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In case of linux `gdb`, upon hitting `abort`, you could see easily stack trace with command `bt`. No need to add extra break point.