# How do I get rid of the Debug Error popup?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, runtime-error

The Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library gives a popup when abort has been called, offering the user a choice of Abort, Retry, or Ignore. I want to bypass this box and just call abort. I've got a signal handler set up to handle exactly how I want the code to exit and handling the abort code can be time sensitive, so I need the code to abort without me having to manually choose abort.

I tried including `_set_error_mode(_OUT_TO_STDERR);` in main, but that doesn't seem to have any effect. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sas1dkb2(v=vs.140).aspx) the API can't be used in the Windows Runtime Library.

Comment: I am not following. How time sensitive crashing the application might be?

Comment: "Abort Retry Ignore" sounds like the debug runtime, not the release runtime.  Thus the dialog box should be a moot point since it doesn't show up in release mode.  See [abort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k089yyh0.aspx).  But why is it important that you get rid of this box in debug mode?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows CRT and assert reporting (abort,retry,ignore)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121698/windows-crt-and-assert-reporting-abort-retry-ignore)