# Prevent "microsoft visual c++ runtime library debug assertion failed" window from appearing upon program crash

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am wondering if there is a way to automatically terminate the program entirely when an exception is thrown, rather than having to choose between the "abort", "retry", and "ignore" buttons on the Visual C++ library window that appears?

[image: Example image].

(example image)

Is there any solution for this? (aside from the obvious -- fixing my code!)

Comment: Build for Release rather than Debug?  But like you say, why not fix the code?

Comment: As far as i can remember this window only appears on machines with a debugger installed

Comment: First, what is there to gain by not showing this window?  Why not fix the error?  As mentioned, this only shows up in the debug runtime, not the release runtime.  The debug runtime is used for that reason -- debugging.  So you should use it for what it is designed for, perceived warts and all.

Comment: I appreciate the comments. Building for release would prevent this from happening. I think it’s neat that there are programmatic workarounds for this as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows CRT and assert reporting (abort,retry,ignore)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121698/windows-crt-and-assert-reporting-abort-retry-ignore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can suppress the message box by passing `_OUT_TO_STDERR` to [`_set_error_mode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/set-error-mode?view=msvc-170).
In case you still get a message box telling you that `abort()` was called and you want to disable it, too, you additionally need to call [`_CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/crtsetreportmode?view=msvc-170).
Full example:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <crtdbg.h>

int main() 
{
  _set_error_mode(_OUT_TO_STDERR);
  _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG);
  assert(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`SetBreakOnAssert(false)` and a whole lot of other things you can (and must) do to prevent this. The problem is that there are many different kind of error mechanisms and error windows.

The one you posted is an ASSERT, which you could disable with SetBreakOnAssert. But you'll still have to deal with the error situation, i.e. terminate the app. There are other cases where the default Windows dialog pops up.

`std::set_terminate` lets you set a function that get's called when any part of your program wants to terminate the application (for example due to a double exception).

`_set_se_translator` lets you specify a function that can translate a Win32 exception such as "Access Violation" to a C++ exception.

`_set_invalid_parameter_handler` lets you specify a function that is called whenever your program calls a std function with invalid parameters. (I think out-of-bounds checking falls into that category).