# How to prevent "Debug assertion failed window" appearing in Visual studio C++ 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2022

I'd like to prevent "Debug assertion failed window" appearing in Visual studio C++ 2022 on errors handled by the debugger, in a way like I pressed "Retry" in this window to get straight to the code.

**Justification**

1. In 99% of cases I press this "Retry" button, so I don't see any value neither in "Abort" (I can stop the app myself) nor in "Ignore" (whatever it is assumed to do), so this is just an excessive step.
2. It produces annoying sound which I can't turn off, since I need it in other cases.

Is this possible keeping debug assertions working and debugger handling these things? I just want to skip the window.

Comment: FYI, using a [site search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=prevent+%22Debug+Assertion+Failed%22+window), there's the quite similar [Prevent "microsoft visual c++ runtime library debug assertion failed" window from appearing upon program crash](/q/71536199), [Windows CRT and assert reporting (abort, retry, ignore)](/q/1121698) and [Is there any way to avoid "Debug Assertion Failed" Window in C++?](/q/68905710), of which I believe some of their answers (even though they are for earlier versions of Visual Studio) may help you to solve your issue.

Comment: @JohnOmielan, thank you. One on the answers worked, I posted it as the answer. (I tried the search before asking, but failed to find this one, only lots of questions where this was related to a particular error in code which caused the window.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to *John Omielan*'s comment above, the answer from here: [Windows CRT and assert reporting (abort, retry, ignore)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121698/windows-crt-and-assert-reporting-abort-retry-ignore) solved the problem:

```
int __cdecl CrtDbgHook(int nReportType, char* szMsg, int* pnRet)
{
    return TRUE;//Return true - Abort,Retry,Ignore dialog will *not* be displayed
    return FALSE;//Return false - Abort,Retry,Ignore dialog *will be displayed*
}
int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])
{
    _CrtSetReportHook2(_CRT_RPTHOOK_INSTALL, CrtDbgHook);
    assert(false);
    getch();
    return 1;
}
```